# Is the Sagan standard a kind of proportionality bias?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, bias

Is the [Sagan standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagan_standard), which says that "extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence", a kind of proportionality bias?

Since the [proportionality bias](http://skepdic.com/proportionalitybias.html) is a tendency to believe that causes are proportional to effects in magnitude, so the Sagan standard seem to fall into that category. Maybe if the standard was a little more specific or it actually defined what it means by extraordinay, then maybe it wouldn't be.